# Implement Custom OpenID ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, jwt, openid

I am using ASP.Net MVC 5 to implement OpenID Authentication.
In my App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs file I have added the following code block

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;

  public partial class Startup
  {
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            Authority = "https://somecustomurl.com/sso/oauth2",
            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            ClientId = "myclientid",
            ClientSecret = "myclientsecret",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            Scope = "openid email",
            AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active
        }); 
  } }
```

I am able to login using my OpenID credentials on the external website but when it's sending me back to my domain then I am getting this error

```
 IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Key tried: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey'.
    token: '{"typ":"JWT","kid":"jdhfgjkfdhgkjgkd","alg":"RS256"}
```

I tried Google for some guidance but was not able to find out something concrete.
Any guidance in resolving this issue will be helpful